# Create a new Instance of an XAML Element

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a ChildWindow which contain a Vectorlight RichTextBox and i need to create a new Instance of the same element every time i show the child.(There is one instance of childwindow which i show and hide many times)

This is the code i use :

```
this.childwindow.rtb = null;
this.childwindow.rtb = new Liquid.RichTextBox();
```

After that the problem is the childwindow is showing a new and empty RichTextBox(maybe the new instancied)
and if i make some changes on this.childwindow.rtb the canges are not rendered.

Thanks
And sorry for my bad english

Comment: Are you sure you need a new instance? You may just need a different DataContext?

Comment: No i need a new instance of the 'rtb' and access to it somehow(this is what i don't know).
Nothing to do with the datacontext in this case.
Thanks Josh C.